# Flask assets searching in the wrong directory

Tags: python, flask, flask-assets

I am trying to get `Flask-Assets` to load my assets.

My css is here: `/home/myname/projects/py/myapp/myapp/static/css/lib/somecsslib.css`

It is by default looking in the wrong directory. I get this:

`No such file or directory: '/home/myname/projects/py/myapp/static/css/lib/somecsslib.css'`

I am initializing it normally;

`assets = Environment(app)`

I tried setting the `load_path`:

`assets.load_path = '/home/myname/projects/py/myapp/myapp/static/'`

When I do that I get the following error:

`BundleError: 'css/lib/somecsslib.css' not found in load path: /home/myname/projects/py/myapp/myapp/static/`

**EDIT**

I just found out that `load_path` is a `list`. 

I tried this instead:
`assets.load_path.append('/home/myname/projects/py/myapp/myapp/static/')`

I got this as a result:
`BuildError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/css/lib/somecsslib.css'`

Comment: What is `app.static_folder`? Flask-Assets looks for files relative to that.

Comment: @dirn Thank you! Geez. My static folder was incorrectly being identified. That was the whole issue.

Answer (score 2):

Flask was incorrectly identifying the location of my static folder. That was the issue. To solve it I told Flask where my static folder sits.

Comment: How did you do this? , I have a similar question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36086581/flask-assets-working-locally-but-not-on-heroku