# Combination of @statsd.timed and @swag_from decorators causes FileNotFoundError

Tags: python, flask, datadog, flasgger

I have a working Flask endpoint decorated with `flasgger.swag_from` decorator:

```py
from flasgger import swag_from

@app.route("/jobs", methods=["GET"])
@swag_from('swagger/get_jobs.yml')
def get_jobs(request_id):
   # ...
```

This works as expected.

I'm using DataDog and would like to *time* every call to this endpoint. Based on [this documentation](https://docs.datadoghq.com/metrics/custom_metrics/dogstatsd_metrics_submission/#code-examples-4), this can easily be achieved by adding the `timed` decorator:

```py
from flasgger import swag_from
from datadog import statsd

@app.route("/jobs", methods=["GET"])
@swag_from('swagger/get_jobs.yml')
@statsd.timed("api_call.duration")
def get_jobs(request_id):
   # ...
```

However - once I do that, I get an error when trying to render the Swagger page:

[image]

The log shows the error is a `FileNotFoundError` caused by Swagger looking for the yml file in the wrong location:

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/datadog/dogstatsd/swagger/backup_sources.yml'

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20943169/flask-assets-searching-in-the-wrong-directory) post, this error sometimes happens when Flask's "static_folder" is configured incorrectly. I've tried changing it, using `Flask(__name__, static_folder='./')`, but the same issue persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue.

Turns out that if you provide a **relative** path to `@swag_from` (as I do above: `swagger/get_jobs.yml`), Flassger "guesses" the root path by calling:

```py
filename = os.path.abspath(obj.__globals__['__file__'])
return os.path.dirname(filename)
```

When I added the `@statsd.timed` decorator **below** the `@swag_from` decorator, I'm basically running the statsd decorator "before" the Flassger one - i.e. the Flassger decorator runs over a wrapper function generated by statsd, which means the `obj.__globals__['__file__']` is the statsd source file, which will make Flassger look for the swagger file under `/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/datadog/dogstatsd`.

The simple workaround is to **reverse the decorator order**, i.e. running the Flasgger decorator "before" the statsd one, by placing it second:

```py
@app.route("/jobs", methods=["GET"])
@statsd.timed("api_call.duration")   # must be above swag_from
@swag_from('swagger/get_jobs.yml')   # must be below statsd.timed
def get_jobs(request_id):
   # ...
```

There might be other solutions - providing an absolute path in `swag_from` or somehow setting a `root_path` attribute on the `get_jobs` method (not sure how to do that).